# Ember app Firebase static file location

Tags: firebase, ember.js, static, firebase-hosting

Can anyone tell me where is my static file located in Firebase if I deploy ember app to Firebase? In my local drive, the static file is under public/assets/ like xxx.pdf ;

BTW everything works as it's meant to be whether locally or from Firebase URL. I just wonder where is the file, so that I can replace/modify directly on Firebase if possible.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your ember app to production on Firebase, all static files are transferred as they are into your public directory which is `dist` so `public/assets/xyz.pdf` will be at `assets/xyz.pdf` in relative to the app root directory.

Comment: however, in firebase console, i can't see my ember file structure, i can only see things like database/storage/hosting etc.  Can you please tell where is file structure located?

Comment: The file structure of your app is not accessible from the console, if you need to access it check your dist folder on your local computer. Among other things your storage usage statistics is also not accessible from Firebase console which is not good. BTW you should use firebase storage to store and serve user-generated content like images, audio, and video.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer.  i will explore more in how to use firebase storage.  But, if i have a file xxx.pdf in both firebase storage and in dist folder, which one will firebase use in the end?